# Is there a solution to get puppeteer (or an alternative) running on Azure Web App Service? (403 issue )

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, puppeteer

We are encountering a problem trying to export a pdf using puppeteer js when releasing our app to the Azure web app service while in local is working well.

Once the puppeteer has launched a headless browser when accessing the page from where it is going to export the pdf we get a file showing a blue page with a 403 forbidden access message.

The site where it is exporting is a public view from the same domain our app is hosted. There is no authentication for this site, we believe the problem has to do with the Azure firewall mechanism trying to stop a headless browser from accessing the server?

Our environment is using Ubuntu 20.04 under a Docker container. We had trouble getting puppeteer running because of the Docker container inside Azure infrastructure but once all dependencies were correctly installed we are not able to successfully export a pdf from the same domain (We tried exporting pdfs from external domains like google.com and works just fine).

Is there a possibility Azure is preventing access for a headless browser or is it a configuration thing we are skipping from the azure portal?

We tried to launch puppeteer browser in many different ways like none headless or without the security sandbox, or using an external chrome binary like `await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: 'wss://chrome.browserless.io/' })` also we have tried [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) for the headless detection and [puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua) to anonymize the User-Agent. None of that has worked so far. This is our result:
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if my reply helps or not, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, Doris, I left a comment below in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to **Networking** page of your web app, check the **Access Restrictions**.
[image]

Refer to the [Azure App Service access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) link:

> When a request is made to your app, the FROM address is evaluated
> against the rules in your access restriction list. If the FROM address
> is in a subnet that's configured with service endpoints to
> Microsoft.Web, the source subnet is compared against the virtual
> network rules in your access restriction list. If the address isn't
> allowed access based on the rules in the list, the service replies
> with an **HTTP 403** status code.

Comment: Besides, you should also check your application logs.

Comment: Hi, @doris-lv thanks for the answer. We tried putting our website IP in the access restriction section and for some reason, I can do a request to our azure website from my local server using a headless browser and it works just fine, but when I do the same from the same server it keeps responding with a 403. I'm guessing it must be an Azure config we are missing or an admin restriction. It is just weird that it works doing this from an external server but not from the same one.

Comment: By the way, we are very new to the Azure platform and what we see in the logs section is not the right info we need, which is the errors and logs from our node app.